# perl 101, getting length of array from using $ on the array variable

Tags: perl

I was expecting this to give the length of the array. Since I thought `$mo` implied scalar context.

But instead, I get the error :

`Global symbol "$mo" requires explicit package name at ./a.pl line 7.`

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @mo = (3,4,5);
print( $mo);
```

UPDATE::
I thought mo is the variable and the sigil $ on $mo is using scalar context. My question is more on the sigil then actually getting the length.

Comment: Despite the similar names, `$mo`, `@mo`, and `%mo` are three completely separate and unrelated variables. Where it gets confusing is that the sigil changes when accessing part of `@mo` or `%mo`, giving you `$mo[0]` (refers to `@mo`, not `$mo`), `$mo{foo}` (`%mo`, not `$mo`), or `@mo{qw(foo bar baz)}` (`%mo` again, not `@mo`). Note that the sigils do _not_ change in Perl 6, presumably in an attempt to avoid this confusion.

Comment: In fact, the `$mo` in your code is being evaluated in list context. The context in which an expression is evaluated is determined by its context (surrounding code), not by the expression itself (`$mo` vs `@mo`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the number of elements in `@mo` use **`scalar @mo`**.

```
my $num_elements = scalar @mo;
```

You can omit the `scalar` when the context dictates that it must be scalar, such as in a comparison:

```
if ($count < @mo) { print "$count is less than the number of elements" }
```

You can also use **`$#mo`**, which is the *index of the last element* (generally one less than the number of elements).

```
my $last_index = $#mo;
```

This is useful when you are iterating through an array and need the array index:

```
for (0..$#mo)
{
   print "Index $_ is $mo[$_]\n";
}
```

The **`$mo`**  form is used when obtaining an element of the array:

```
my $second_element = $mo[1];
```

**`$mo`** just by itself is a totally separate variable (though you probably shouldn't create such a variable, as it would be confusing).

Comment: @airnet, you are correct that `$` indicates scalar.  However, the primary way of using an array as a scalar is by accessing an array element.  Thus `$array[0]` is what it is used for.

Comment: Also there is a difference between a "scalar variable" and "scalar context".

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to print a scalar variable `$mo` which does not exist. You need to use the array name in scalar context as:

```
my @mo = (3,4,5);
print scalar @mo;
```

Another way is to use `$#mo` which would return the largest index in the array which in your case is 2.

Comment: I thought mo is the variable and the sigil $ on $mo is using scalar context.

Comment: @airnet: No. In Perl you can have a scalar and an array with the same name. `$mo` and `@mo` are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You may get length of an array as

1. > my $mo = @mo; 
   >       print $mo;
2. > my $mo = scalar (@mo); 
   >       print $mo;
3. > my $mo = $#mo + 1; 
   >   print $mo;